# Why does append.Child return me null when I use it in a Div but works when I put it on the body?

Tags: javascript, html, css, append, appendchild

for some reason my code doesn't work. When I try to see what the console will return me it gives me the answer I want while returning me: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" when I the same thing on for a Div.

This is my code please help me...

```
function addOnePropertie () {
    var theUl = document.createElement ("UL");
    var theText = document.createTextNode ("This is a paragraph.");
    theUl.appendChild (theText);
    document.getElementById('theUlDiv').appendChild (TheUl); 
}

<div class="divOne">
    <header>
        Sign Up an Object
    </header>

    <ul>
        <span class="spanObject"> Name of Object: </span>
        <input placeholder="Type any Name...">
    </ul>
        <hr class="inDiv">
    <ul>
        <span class="spanObject"> Name plus Value of Propertie One: </span>
        <input class="smallInput" placeholder="Name of Propertie..."> 
        <input class="smallInput" placeholder="Value of Propertie">
    </ul>
    <div id="theUlDiv">
    </div>
    <button class="addPropertie" onclick="addOnePropertie ();">
        Add a Propertie 
        <i class="material-icons" style="color: blue; font-size: 15px;"> 
            note_add 
        </i>
    </button>
</div>
```

As you see if I `console.log (theUl)` it returns me what I want a new Ul element, same if I try to put it in `document.body.appendChild (theUl)`, but if I do it in the div it doesn't work, please help me out :D

Comment: Why do you try to put plain text directly to `<ul>`?

Comment: And target div in html has class `theUlDiv` but you try to find it by id

Comment: Yes, this was a very stupid mistake by me, not to see class instead of id but even so, it returns me the exact same thing... null and doesnt work!

Comment: Change your function definition to `window.addOnePropertie = function () {` and then fix some errors with variables naming and then it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to debug this will be, try to query in your browser console for the element, `document.getElementById('theUlDiv')` and you will find that it will return null because your markup doesn't have an element with `id='theULDiv'` either use `document.getElementsByClassName('theUlDiv')[0]` or change your markup to add the `id` to the element.
**Edit:**
There is another error in this line `.appendChild (TheUl);` inside appendChild method you are passing an undefined variable. your actual variable is `theUl` but you have capital 'T'

Comment: Yes, this was a very stupid mistake by me, not to see class instead of id but even so, it returns me the exact same thing... null and doesnt work!

Comment: There is another error in this line `.appendChild (TheUl);`  inside appendChild function you are passing an undefined variable. your actual variable is `theUl` but you have capital 'T'

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed the problem :D miss spelling all the way haha im so stupid sometimes :D

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no element which `id` is 'theUlDiv' in your html.

Comment: Yes, this was a very stupid mistake by me, not to see class instead of id but even so, it returns me the exact same thing... null and doesnt work!